# Excel VBA - Adjust Color Line and X-Axis Interval

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I used Excel VBA to create a chart and I want to adjust the line color and x-axis interval.

Below is the code:

```
Sub add_cpu_chart(server_hostname, site)
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim rpt_site As String
    rpt_site = site

    Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(server_hostname).ListObjects(1)
    strTableName = tbl.Name
    strTableRange = tbl.Range.Address

    Dim m_s_name, m_e_name As Date

    m_s_name = CDate(fromDateStr)
    m_e_name = CDate(toDateStr)

    'Create new embedded chart
    Set shp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(server_hostname).Shapes.AddChart

    'Position Shape over range

    shp.Top = 100
    shp.Left = 200

    With shp
        With .Chart
            'Specify source data and orientation
            '.SetSourceData Source:=ActiveSheets.Range(Table1 & "[#All]"), _
            'PlotBy:=xlRows
            .SetSourceData Source:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(server_hostname).Range(strTableName & "[#All]")
            .ChartType = xlLineMarkers
            .SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
            .HasTitle = True
            .ChartTitle.Text = "CPU Utilization of " & server_hostname & " in " & _
            rpt_site & " (" & Format(m_s_name, "dd-Mmm") & " to " & Format(m_e_name, "dd-Mmm yyyy") & ")"
            .ChartTitle.Font.Size = 14
            '.ChartArea.Font.Size = 14
            .Legend.Delete

            .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueAxisTitleRotated)
            .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "CPU Utlization (%)"
            .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Font.Size = 10
            .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 0
            .Axes(xlValue).MinorUnit = 2
            .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 100
            .Axes(xlValue).MajorUnit = 20
            .Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "General"

            .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryCategoryAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis)
            .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Date of the Month"
            .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Font.Size = 10
            '.Axes(xlCategory).MajorUnit = 1
            .Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "d"
            With .PlotArea.Format.Fill
                .Visible = msoTrue
                .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorBackground1
                .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
                .ForeColor.Brightness = -0.150000006
                .Transparency = 0
                .Solid
            End With
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

I want to change the line color to red - as in excel 2003 - as well as change the data in interval separated by 2 days. Currently, the data is in the form `1,2,3,4...` I want to display the data in the form `1,3 ,5...`.

Comment: `I want to show 1 ,3 ,5..` So where are you stuck? What error are you getting? Though I doubt you are getting any error as you start off with `On Error Resume Next`. Remove that line :)

Comment: @Ivan Chan, if you find a useful solution that resolves your issue, please mark it as accepted. Otherwise, people may become hesitant to answer your questions in a useful way.

Answer (score 6):

In a line chart, the X axis' minimumscale, maximum scale, majorunit, and minorunit are meaningless. The X values are merely categories which have no interpreted numerical values even if the labels show numerals.

You should probably change to an XY chart, which will allow full control over the axis scale using minimumscale, maximum scale, majorunit, and minorunit. Of course, an XY chart allows the same formatting of series markers and lines as in a line chart, but the confusing terminology will live on forever.

If for some reason you decide to stick with a line chart, you can use

```
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabelSpacing = 2
```